# socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, AF_INET) uses IGMP?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

If I print out the header field values of the IP header sent on a the RAW socket with the following parameters and default settings, I see that the protocol number is set to '2' which belongs to that of IGMP.

```
 sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, AF_INET);
```

However, if I access the packet using TCP header, I get good values for most of the fields, except that data offset gets a wrong value. Also, I am not able to read the header correctly using IGMP headers on the Linux platform (Ubuntu).

For reading out the header:

```
printf("\n");
printf("IP Header\n");
printf("   |-IP Version        : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->version);
printf("   |-IP Header Length  : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)iph->ihl,  ((unsigned int)(iph->ihl))*4);
printf("   |-Type Of Service   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->tos);
printf("   |-IP Total Length   : %d  Bytes(Size of Packet)\n",ntohs(iph->tot_len));
printf("   |-Identification    : %d\n",ntohs(iph->id));
printf("   |-TTL      : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->ttl);
printf("   |-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->protocol);
printf("   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
printf("   |-Source IP        : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
printf("   |-Destination IP   : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));

// IGMP Print
printf("\n");
printf("IGMP Header\n");
printf("   |-IGMP Type        : %d\n",(unsigned int)head->igmp_type);
printf("   |-IGMP Code        : %d\n",(unsigned int)head->igmp_code);
printf("   |-IGMP Checksum    : %d\n",(unsigned int)head->igmp_cksum);
printf("   |-IGMP Address     : %s\n",inet_ntoa(head->igmp_group.sin_addr);
```

This gives me error for IGMP Packet:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

For all 4 fields.

If I treat it as TCP header, it works fine.

I am using RAW socket to communicate between a daemon and a CLI as its management agent.

Comment: Could it be that the other end of the connection sends TCP packets? What's the value of `iph->protocol`?

Comment: Both sides are on the local host, and using same protocols.

Comment: And both are using raw sockets? And you are sure the sender does not send TCP packets?

Comment: I am the sender, and the receiver too. Both sides use identical sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've seriously failed to understand what raw sockets are for. They're a tool to let you manually assemble or inspect the contents of IP packets, including the higher-level headers inside the IP packet that tell whether it's TCP, UDP, ICMP, IGMP, etc. They **are not a means of communication** to be used directly, but a means to hack around with existing higher-level means of communication at a lower level.

For your application you almost certainly want TCP or UDP sockets.

Comment: I am new to socket programming, and I surely don't fully understand the purpose. I understand that RAW sockets are usually used as sniffers or to send routing updates directly to the kernel and to develop support for protocols which are not supported by the Kernel as such. But I am experimenting with various options as a part of learning and right now am trying to send and receive packets without explicitly binding to a particular port. I read somewhere that UNIX domain sockets may be used for CLI-daemon communication, but there must be other alternatives too. Could you please suggest some?

Comment: What you should understand is that these options are not simply different cosmetic choices you can make, like what color you want your iPhone to be. ;-) They all have very different purposes. Now that you mention unix sockets, if they fit your needs they're almost certainly the best option. Because they're machine-local and have owner-based permissions like files, you can avoid the cost and risks of developing your own authentication mechanism for the connection...

Comment: As for "send and receive packets without explicitly binding to a particular port", could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: As I said, I am trying to send and receive packets without explicitly binding to ports. In TCP sockets, using the client-server model, we need to first bind the socket to a port to listen for incoming connection requests and then for every new connection, a socket descriptor is returned which then handles the rest of the processing. I don't want that listening socket, knowing that request will always come from only one daemon on a specified port and straightaway handle the incoming message for further processing.

Comment: This is primarily because if I use the traditional client-server model, then I'll have to take care of registering the new file descriptor in the API and also write separate cases to distinguish between an 'Open Connection request' and 'Data Message' packets.

Comment: I think a UDP socket would achieve exactly what you want without requiring hideous hacks.